# Etale fundamental groups of the projective line and the affine line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

> **Theorem 1** Let $X$ be a normal integral scheme, $K$ its function field, $\bar{K}$
>   an algebraic closure of $K$, and $M$ the composite of all finite
>   separable field extensions $L$ of $K$ with $L\subset K$ for which $X$
>   is unramified in $L$. Then the fundamental group $\pi(X)$ is
>   isomorphic to the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(M/K)$.

[image]

In the above paragraphs Theorem 1 at the beginning of this post is being used to compute the etale fundamental groups of $\mathbb P_{K}^1$ and $\mathbb A_{K}^1$.

I've difficulty in understanding the difference between the two cases.

In particular, I'm particular I've difficulty in understanding how to figure out if  a finite extension of $F$ of $k(t)$ is unramified over
$\mathbb P_{K}^1$ or $\mathbb A_{K}^1$?

And in case  $\mathbb A_{K}^1$ are we looking only at valuations $v_f$ (and **not** $v_{\infty}$) and checking if $F$ is unramified at all these valuations?

In case of  $\mathbb P_{K}^1$ are we looking at all the valuations $v_f$ and $v_{\infty}$ and checking if $F$ is unramified at all these valuations? Is that the difference? Why is checking at $v_{\infty}$ and $v_f$ enough in this case?

Comment: What book is this from?  Ah, I see, it's [*Galois theory for schemes* by Lenstra](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf).

Comment: I suggest to fix your ideas to think about the case when $K$ is algebraically closed, so that $\pi(K)$ is trivial. Then, as you said, you are looking at extensions where $\nu_f$ is unramified for all finite valuations in the case of $\mathbb{A}^1$ and you will also need the same for $\nu_{\infty}$ for the projective line. These are all the valuations of $K(t)$, which is zero on $K$, up to equivalence. Finally, in characteristic $p>0$, you must keep in mind Artin-Schreier extensions (for example, $K(t,x)$ with $x^p+x+t=0$).